# How to roll back to an earlier insider build?

Tags: insider-preview

My L930 is running Windows 10 build 14295 which caused insane battery drain (as I stated in a previous question) I love the new features on this update but 3 hours of battery life just doesn't cut it. I read that people downgraded to an earlier Win 10 build to solve this for now. How can I do this too?

Answer (score 2):

I think Windows Device Recovery Tool may not help you in this case as the Lumia 930 was originally released with Windows 8.1 & Microsoft has not released Windows 10 Mobile for all Lumia Phones. However if you want to go to previous build, the option to download desired previous build may not be available. Only latest releases (Fast, Slow, Production & Release Review) option will be available. So install Windows 8.1 on your Lumia 930 & again upgrade it to Windows 10 Mobile. I will recommend you to only use production ring for your PRIMARY device as they are more stable than fast or slow rings. To check preview builds only a secondary device should be used as they have bugs & comparatively unstable.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Windows Lumia Recovery Tool Software for that issue.

Comment: I tried, but it only gives the option to roll back to WP 8.1. But I just want a previous Win 10 build.